# Continuity call handoff no longer does

Tags: iphone, mac-pro, ios, continuity

Since upgrading to iOS 10 and macOS 10.12 at about the same time, I can no longer handoff calls from my iPhone to my Mac.

When a call comes in I get the notification window appearing on my Mac, as before. When I click the "answer" (or whatever it is) button, it pauses for a moment, gives an error message, and then the iPhone disconnects the call.

BT is turned on on both devices, both are connected to the same WiFi, Handoff is turned on on both machines. Any ideas?

Comment: There's hundreds of articles written on the net to help troubleshoot Handoff issues.  To avoid us repeating what you've already tried, and wasting everyone's time, please edit your question to include what you've already done to fix the problem yourself.

Comment: I visited about a half dozens such pages and they all said the things I put in the OP - that is, compatible hardware, same network, BT turned on, all the switches turned on. If you know of a page with better testing steps, by all means, post away!

Comment: Well, for starters, posting the actual error message instead of just "an error message" would be very helpful.

Comment: And now it works perfectly. Apparently a bug in macOS 10.12.